# Prove that spaces $C^k(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ are infinite dimensional.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, vector-spaces

> Prove that spaces  $C^k(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ are infinite dimensional.

So in order to prove that they're infinite dimensional spaces, I need to form a linearly independent sequence which is infinite. Would I simply pick polynomials? (i.e. $1,x,x^2,\dots$ as my basis?)

Comment: Yes looks good. Just note that you have $n$ variables so $x$ is a function of the form $f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=x_1$.

Answer (score 5):

Yes and no. Yes, because they form an infinite linearly independent family, and that is enough to prove what you want to prove. And no because they do *not* form a basis.